# Find the distance between a point and given parametric line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the distance of the point 
$(3,6,−5)$

from the line 
$r(t)=\langle 1+3t,1+4t,5−3t\rangle$.

Comment: you want to find the orthogonal complement of the vector <3,6,5> with respect to the line. The length of this component is the distance.

Answer (score 1):

Let the nearest point from $A(3,6,-5)$ on this line be $ B(1+3t_0,1+4t_0,5-3t_0)$. Then vector $AB=(3t_0-2,4t_0-5,10-3t_0)$ Since this is perpendicular to this line, it's dot product with direction ratios of line is 0.
$$\Longrightarrow(3t_0-2)(3)+(4t_0-5)(4)+(10-3t_0)(-3)=0$$
Solve for $t_0$ and hence find distance between $A$ and $B$.

**Another Method**
Directly apply the formula for distance between two parallel lines, assuming another line to pass through the given point with same direction ratios as the given line.
$$ distance=\frac{|b×(a_2-a_1)|}{|b|}$$
where $b$ is direction vector of given line $(=(3,4,-3))$ $a_2$ and $a_1$ are points on parallel lines( which are (1,1,5) and (3,6,-5) in this case).

Hope it helps